# java create custom jpanel and use as a template

Tags: java, swing

[image]

i want to create  java component looks like  my picture, because i'm gonna use it manytimes in my application .my idea is add a jpanel[left panel] and a Jlable [right lable] to a jpanel[main panel]. Main panel is the final object which i want to use again and again.

so my first step is create a main panel.and try to use it as a template.but i realized it's not work as i expected .this is my template class this is the class which i going to use again and again.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class customCompo extends JPanel {
    void customCompoMeth() {

        JPanel green = new JPanel();
        green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 150));
        green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

i have a another class which consist main method.here it is.how i use my above template  again and again.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 customCompo c1=new customCompo();

 jPanel1.add(c1);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

what i'm doing here is create new instance and add it to a component in this case Jpanel1.but it's not working .it gives me errors .i need a help  what's my wrong ?am i completely wrong?

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you. As it currently stands, we can't answer your question.

Comment: Why this thread got two up-votes, I'll never understand.  -1 for balance.  Always copy/paste error & exception output, and as suggested by @Laf, post an MCVE.

Comment: I hope you understand the concept of class extending the functionality of the super class and a simple class. Just answer yourself, how and what line in that code made `customComp` a `JPanel or a JComponent`, in the code that you had written.

Comment: i'm not talking about creating jpanel .i'm talking about create custom jpanel and use it as java default component .

Comment: You mean to say in an `IDE`, if YES then which `IDE`? If you simply wanted to enhance the features of already existing `JPanel`(provided by Java by default), then obviously you have to extend it and provide some features to it, as need be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am able to understand the question in the correct way now, you simply wanted to create one `JPanel` with some added thingies to it, that one can reuse again and again, without writing the whole code. If that be the case, one simply needs to extend the `JPanel` and simply put the modifications one needs and reuse it, whereever needed, as already said by @peeskillet.

Do see this code example, and see if this is what you referring to:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ExampleTemplate {

    private static final int GAP = 5;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, GAP, GAP));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        contentPane.add(new TemplatePanel());
        contentPane.add(new TemplatePanel());
        contentPane.add(new TemplatePanel());

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExampleTemplate().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class TemplatePanel extends JPanel {

    private Random r;
    private JPanel leftPanel;

    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public TemplatePanel() {
        r = new Random();
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(getRandomColor());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));      
        JPanel footerPanel = getPanel();
        footerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.8;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        leftPanel = getPanel();
        footerPanel.add(leftPanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.2;
        JLabel rightLabel = new JLabel("Right Label", JLabel.CENTER);
        footerPanel.add(rightLabel);

        JLabel centerLabel = new JLabel("Main Panel", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(centerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(getRandomColor());

        return panel;
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(),
                            r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> "but it's not working .it gives me errors"

The first error I see in that little bit of code you provided, is the fact that you are trying to add an instance of a non-component class to a JPanel. That will fail. You should make the class extend JComponent, JPanel, or any other JComponent, if you want to add it to another panel.

See [Creating GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). You may need to get up to speed on the basics :)